# bash permissions

Tags: command-line, server, bash, permissions

My friend was trying to tighten up security on his ubuntu server and changed the permissions on bash. He logged out, and now the computer won't let him log back in.

The server is an off-site server (I believe it is running ubuntu 12.10), so we only have command-line access to it. We can't actually see what is happening on screen until it has booted because of remote stuff, so we can't just tell it to go to root mode when it is booting. He says that we still the ability to ssh into the machine. Right now when we try to login, it logs in, the immediately logs us back out.

Is there a way to log in directly as root, or tell ubuntu to run sh commands from the login page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do `ssh -t user@host some_other_shell`, where some_other_shell is something like sh, ksh, zsh, etc.